# How can I select the correct option in select box in a nested loop in mustache?

Tags: clojure, mustache

I'm having a nested loop that generates `<select>` tags, and I want to set them to a certain value.
I thought I could create a lambda `{{selected}}` that would take the context and check if it's the correct value for this selectbox. Except I'd also need the id from the `{{team}}` array.

For a single select, you could include a `selected` boolean in `champions`, but this gets messy pretty quick quick select boxes.

Would there be a way to get the needed info, or another way to generated the `selected` attribute? I'm using Clojure's Stencil with data the looks like this:

```
  {:params {"winner0" 16, "winner1" 4, ...}
   :champions [{:name "Soraka", :id 16}, ...]
   :team (range 5)
   :selected (fn [] if params[idx] == champion-id: return selected)}
```

HTML excerpt:

```
  <form method="get" action="">
          {{#team}}
                  <select name="winner{{.}}">
                      <option value="">None</option>
                      {{#champions}}
                      <option {{selected}} value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
                      {{/champions}}
                  </select>
          {{/team}}
      <input type="submit" value="Recommend my pick!" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mustache templates are supposed to be "dumb". Even though there exist a [lambda](https://github.com/davidsantiago/stencil/blob/master/test/stencil/test/extensions.clj#L16) construct, it has very limited capabilities. Your best bet is to transform the data so it's already "massaged" for the template. Clojure shines here: it has very powerful data transformation primitives.

Here's an example (reduced for brevity) based on yours:

```
(require '[stencil.core :as stencil])

(def form "{{#teams}}
              <select name='winner{{id}}'>
                <option value=''>None</option>
                {{#champions}}
                <option {{#selected}}selected='selected' {{/selected}}value='{{id}}'>{{name}}</option>
                {{/champions}}
              </select>
           {{/teams}}")


(let [data {:params {"winner0" 16, "winner1" 4}
            :champions [{:name "Soraka", :id 16}
                        {:name "champ4" :id 4}
                        {:name "champ5" :id 5}]}]
  (->> (range 2)
       (map (fn [team-id]
              (let [winner (get (:params data) (str "winner" team-id))]
                {:id team-id
                 :champions (map #(assoc % :selected (= (:id %) winner))
                                 (:champions data))})))
       (hash-map :teams)
       (stencil/render-string form))
```

Result:

```html
<select name='winner0'>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <option value=''>None</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  <option selected='selected' value='16'>Soraka</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <option value='4'>champ4</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  <option value='5'>champ5</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</select>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<select name='winner1'>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <option value=''>None</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  <option value='16'>Soraka</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  <option selected='selected' value='4'>champ4</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <option value='5'>champ5</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</select>
```

Even though that seems to do what you need, if you have the chance to choose I strongly recommend using something like [hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup). It's a DSL to represent html using clojure data structures, so it's very expressive and powerful.

Comment: I started out with Hiccup, but after fighting with it and its `hiccup.form/select-options` for a while, I fell back to something I knew better.

Comment: Ok. I just updated the answer, I hope the code is more clear now. Either with hiccup or stencil, you should first transform the raw data. It's a bit difficult to understand what's the underlying model by looking at the raw data from your question. Something like `{:teams [{:id 1 :champions [{:id 1 :name "..." :selected true} {:id 2 :name "..." :selected false}]} {:id 2 :champions [....]}]` is much more clear and easy to render both with hiccup and mustache